# Excel/VBA: Rename files based on contents

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, batch-file

I need to move a series of files based on their content. Ideally, this could be triggered from inside Excel since the user is importing the files.  I can do this with a simple Unix shell script as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
for F in $(ls *.csv)
  do  
   while read N W
   do
     if grep -q "$W" "$F"
     then
      NEW=${N:0:50}.csv
        echo $F $NEW
        cp "$F" WORKING/$NEW
        break
      fi
  done <  ../Documents/ASSET\ Sale/bin/fixfilenames_namemap.txt
done

cp Name*.csv WORKING/name_name2.csv
```

The format of the fixfilesnames_namemap.txt is:

```
newfilename text search string
newfilename2 text search string number two
```

Note that the last line is a kludge as that file has a bunch of spaces in its name and so it fails to get called properly in the loop and so I just move the one file.

I'd like a VBA routine that would run or perhaps a simple .bat file that I could trigger from inside Excel 2016.

Currently, I'm working with a RenameFile() function that allows me to specify directory, source and newname.  If I could just get a search function working to find a text string in another field I'm all set.

```
Public Function RenameFile()
Dim src As String, dst As String, fl As String
Dim rfl As String

'Folder
src = Range("F4")
'File name
fl = Range("G4")
'Rename file
rfl = Range("Assets_Eligible_Destination")

On Error Resume Next
Name src & "\" & fl As src & "\" & rfl
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    MsgBox "Error: " & src & "\" & rfl
End If
On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Thanks

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code works to find the string from a sheet in a set of files. However it is very slow if you files are 100K lines and the matching line is in the last 10.

This is based on another StackOverflow answer: 
[How do I find a specific string in one of many text .log files using VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17860618/how-do-i-find-a-specific-string-in-one-of-many-text-log-files-using-vba)

```
Sub StringExistsInFile()
  Dim theString As String
  Dim path As String
  Dim StrFile As String
  Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
  Dim file As TextStream
  Dim line As String

  theString = Range("E4")
  path = Range("F4")
  StrFile = Dir(path & "*.csv")

  Do While StrFile <> ""

    'Find TheString in the file
    'If found, debug.print and exit loop

    'Set file = fso.OpenTextFile(path & StrFile)


    Do While Not file.AtEndOfStream
        line = file.ReadLine

'Debug.Print line

        If InStr(1, line, theString, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            Range("G4").Value = StrFile
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop

    file.Close
    Set file = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing

    StrFile = Dir()
  Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Regarding speed: you *might* get better performance by 1) reading as binary using a specific buffer size (e.g. `readblock` and "large" buffer like 1024) (but has a drawback, see below) and; 2) using the excel function `CountIF` which is purportedly much faster. I expect that reading line-by-line may protect you from the case where a "dumb" buffer splits the text you are searching for, but perhaps you instead do multiple readlines and then do a search on a bigger chunk.

Comment: In the past, I messed around with some VB file splitting and rejoining and noted that a buffer of about 1024 bytes per read/write was "as fast" as a `copy /b foo1.txt + foo2.txt joined.txt`, and anything less got significantly slower.

Comment: also: with some form of GREP for windows, you might be able to port your bash script. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/87350/what-are-good-grep-tools-for-windows

Comment: The bash script works on Windows.  The reason to port to VBA is to get a routine that is encapsulated within the Excel file itself. Given the user base, this Excel file is going to be in several hands and I don't want to tie it to the "perfect environment".

Comment: One approach is to try and have a version of TAIL written in VBA ... working on one now.

Comment: You didn't state the positioning of the type in question, but "yeah" a quick optimization is to read the first 10 lines, the last 10 lines. and then the middle IIF not found.